# Using spatie(laravel-permission) in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-permission

When Assigning permission for a role using seeder, in permissions table it will take guard_name as "web",
but when adding permission through CRUD, it will take guard_name as "sanctum".
At the time of assigning this new permission to Role it will give an error.

RoleTableSeeder.php:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('roles')->delete();
    $roles_json = File::get("database/seeders/data/roles.json");
    $perms_json = File::get("database/seeders/data/permissions.json");
    $roles_data = json_decode($roles_json);
    $perms_data = json_decode($perms_json);
    Log::info("Starting Roles Population...");
    foreach ($roles_data->roles as $role) {
        $rl = Role::create([
            'name' => $role->name,
            'role_desc' => $role->role_desc
        ]);

        $rol = Role::findOrFail($rl['id']);
        foreach ($perms_data->permissions as $perm) {
            $per = Permission::findOrFail($perm->id);
            $rol->givePermissionTo($per);
        }
        Log::info("Populating... " . $role->name );
    }
    Log::info("Roles Populated Successfully.");
}
```

RoleController:

```
//---Assign Permission to Role
public function PermissionToRole($request, $id) {
    $selectedRole = Role::find($id);
    $selectedRolePermissions = $selectedRole->getAllPermissions();

    $users = User::role($id)->get();

    //---Remove Selected Role To Permissions
    for ($i=0; $i < count($selectedRolePermissions); $i++) {
        $selectedRole->revokePermissionTo($selectedRolePermissions[$i]);
    }

    if ($request->input('option') != null)
    {
        for ($k=0; $k < count($request->input('option')); $k++)
        {
            //---Insert New Permission To Role
            $findPermission = Permission::find($request->input('option')[$k]);
            $selectedRole->givePermissionTo($findPermission);
            //---Remove Old Permissions From User & Assign New Permissions To Users
            for ($m = 0 ; $m < count($users) ; $m++) {
                for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($users[$m]->getDirectPermissions()) ; $j++) {
                    if ($findPermission->id == $users[$m]->getDirectPermissions()[$j]->id) {
                        $users[$m]->revokePermissionTo($users[$m]->getDirectPermissions()[$j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return back()->with('success', '');
    }
}//---End of Function PermissionToRole
```

How to get both guard_name as "web" not "sanctum" because when assigning this permission to Role I get an error:
[image: The Error when assigning permission to role]

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('pertorole/{role_id}', 'Roles\RoleController@PerToRoleEdit')->name('role.pertoroleedit')->middleware('can:Assign Permission');
Route::patch('pertorole/{role_id}', 'Roles\RoleController@PerToRoleUpdate')->name('role.pertoroleupdate')->middleware('can:Assign Permission');
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
];
```

}

Comment: can you show your `app/Http/Kernel.php` and route file?

Comment: I have added the Kernel.php in the question

Comment: Spatie currently have 349 projects in their Github account so please when you ask questions about one or more of those projects you need to explicitly specify which one and tag as appropriate. The generic company tag is not really useful here.

Comment: I was asking about spatie laravel role and permission(spatie/laravel-permission).

Answer (score 0):

add `protected $guard_name = 'web';` to your User model.
sanctum default guard is "web".